# Using returning the evaluation of backticks for a template javascript function not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Attempting to generate a `package.json` with node and it works if I define the function like this:

```
const generatePackageJson = (name) => {
    const package = 
    `
    {
        "name": "${name}",
    }
    `;
    return package;
}
```

The `package` string returned contains the name parameter.  However doing this does not work:

```
const generatePackageJson = (name) => {
    return
    `
    {
        "name": "${name}",
    }
    `;
}
```

The result returned is `undefined`.  Just curious as to why this is?

Comment: Because you aren't returning the object, the interpreter is using automatic semicolon insertion, so it thinks you are doing `return;` instead of `return {}`

Comment: Your first example now works. In your second example, `return` can't be on the line by itself. You need to start the opening backpack on the same line.

Comment: AHA!  Got it - Thanks.  Moving the backtick to the same line as the return statement fixed it.

Comment: I returns undefined because in the line you return there is nothing, if you move the backtick to the line up it will return fine.